# jBPM - Can we fetch process variables in task Listeners?

Tags: task, jbpm

I have written a custom Task Event listener. In that on the After task added event I am changing some process variables.

How can i fetch process variables in Task event listeners ?

Any help is aprreciated.

Comment: I guess this is not possible in jBPM. There is no access to process variables in jBPM Task event life cycles. and no work around for it as well.  it would've been nice had it been there.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider passing the process variable as task variable through mapping so that process variable is available in the task context. Use the task variable mapped with the process variable inside task listener